# Problem with creating visualization for multimaster ROS system

Tags: navigation, rviz, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have 3 turtlebots and one computer to control/ssh them. It's a multimaster ROS system- each turtlebot runs its own rosmaster. I group all the individual robot topics in a group so they get their appropriate namespaces. Ex. turtle01/amcl_pose, etc. Each robot saves a map of my lab area and loads it during startup. I am using multimaster_fkie for this setup.

My questions:
Can I create a single rviz file, view all the robots together in one map on my computer and all of them performing amcl to estimate their location?

When I run more than 1 robot on the same map, my robot pose gets messed up. It looks like this.

I am unable to figure out the reason behind this.

When I run the minimal.launch file on each robot, all the topics get the namespace except /tf, /tf_static and /scan. When I launch multiple robots together, won't this create a problem?
This is how the topics look like.

```
dslam@turtlebot01:~$ rostopic list  
/diagnostics  
/rosout  
/rosout_agg  
/scan  
/tf  
/tf_static  
/turtle01/amcl/parameter_descriptions  
/turtle01/amcl_pose
```

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277571/problem-with-creating-visualization-for-multimaster-ros-system/) by [VickyD](https://answers.ros.org/users/32904/vickyd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-12-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-07**:
Instead of linking to images of terminal output, can you please copy and paste it here? This helps to keep the question self-contained and has the benefit of being searchable.

**Comment by [VickyD](https://answers.ros.org/users/32904/vickyd/) on 2017-12-08**:
I've corrected it now. Thank you for suggesting that!

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-08**:
I've given you some karma, can you please see if you can insert your image into your question instead of hosting it externally?

**Comment by [VickyD](https://answers.ros.org/users/32904/vickyd/) on 2017-12-21**:
Sure. I wanted to do the same but I didn't have enough karma. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you can have a single rviz configuration file for viewing all the robots together while each is using amcl to estimate its pose. That's how I do it.

As for the namespace issue, I believe that having the `/tf` and `/tf_static` topics *not* be in their own namepsaces is  common. However, you should have each robot's `/scan` topic be in its own namespace (the same of the robot that is producing the laser scans).

[This answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/41433/multiple-robots-simulation-and-navigation/?answer=41434#post-id-41434) really helped me  out with setting up a multi-robot simulation. You can extend these ideas into a configuring up your real-world setup (you'll have to adapt it to fit your multi-master situation). Don't be turned off of the date of the question either, much of it is still applicable.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-21**:
@VickyD if this answer solved your question, please mark it as correct by clicking on the check mark.

**Comment by [VickyD](https://answers.ros.org/users/32904/vickyd/) on 2017-12-21**:
Yes, you were correct. The tf tree is shared among all the robots. All the topics are under their own namespaces except `/tf` and `/tf_static`. One of my node was either incorrectly publishing or subscribing to `/scan` topic and so I was able to see it in `rostopic list` output. Thank you!